# Store historical attributes in one SOLR document

Tags: date, solr, lucene, schema, historical-db

I am building a SOLR cluster where each solr document corresponds to data about a company. For example, the following attributes are tracked:

```
1. name
2. size
3. location
4. awards
5. profit
```

My problem is that I also want to track **historical** data for the attributes that may change (such as size/awards). I know the easy way to do this is to have a document in SOLR for each time range. So If I wanted to get all companies that were under size 50 from 2012 - 2013 it's a simple SOLR query. However, I'm dealing with close to 20 million companies. And using the above strategy means that every time one attribute changes, we duplicate that document - dramatically increasing the number of documents in the solr cluster.

I am trying to think of a clever way to use fields in SOLR so I can track the deprecated attributes and their dates within the main *companies* document. But I can't seem to work out a good way to do it. I know that is partially because this problem isn't what SOLR was designed for and storing data this way means it's not properly normalized. However, I am just looking for a good way to avoid massively duplicating my data.

Key use case is to be able to execute queries like:

```
select all companies that were under size 50 from 2012 to 2013
```

So each attribute has to be linked to a value, a date valid, and a date deprecated field. Also the attribute value and dates must be searchable.

I want to do something like this:

```
{  
   "size":[  
      {  
         "date_deprecated": None,
         "date_valid":"2015-01-01",
         "value":"100"
      },
      {  
         "date_deprecated":"2014-12-31",
         "date_valid":"2014-01-01",
         "value":"50"
      },
      {  
         "date_deprecated":"2013-12-31",
         "date_valid":"2013-01-01",
         "value":"25"
      }
   ]
}
```

But obviously that doesn't fly in SOLR. Also, the attributes (fields) are dynamic as I use a dynamic solr schema. So I don't necessary know what all the attributes are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you going to be _searching_ through that historical data? If not, it should not be in Solr.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch Yes. I would like to be able to search and get a list of all companies with a particular attribute that had a particular value between one date and another. Using the example from above I would like to query SOLR and get a list of all companies that were under size 50 from 2012 to 2013

Answer (score 0):

Duplication of the data may not be a big deal if you use Solr for search only and don't **store** the field content, but only index it. The indexed values even if it shows up in 20 documents are stored once and then only the the documents that contain them are listed.

So, you could have your primary data source with all the fields somewhere else and use Solr for search.

Comment: Ideally we would like to store all our data in SOLR as well.

Comment: You should not use Solr as the primary database. It is designed and optimized for search. While it is very reliable, the correct architecture will still store the primary data somewhere else. You do have other options with avoid data duplication in Solr, including parent/children entities, external value fields, etc. But all have even more complicated trade-offs. It might be best to build a prototype first and experiment with impact on your specific data.